# How to change the value

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-8.5

Using Crystal Report 9

Column from table

```
ID Qty

01 100
02 300
03 200
...
...
```

From the above table, i want to make a qty = 0 if id = 3

```
If id = 3 then qty = 0
```

How to make a formula.

Need Crystal Report Formula Help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Crystal syntax:
`if {table.ID}=3 then 0 else {table.quantity}`

Just use that formula anywhere in the report where you would normally use the database field {table.quantity}.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [formula](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225356%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) like follows, the following is only the example which I applied to one of my crystal reports.

**Example:**

```
if(ToText({AgentLoginHistory;1.StatusText})= "ONLINE")Then
 formula = "LoggedIn"
else
 formula = {AgentLoginHistory;1.StatusText}
end if
```